# -$2 balance in US Bank that may grow big

Tags: united-states, banking

About a few months ago USBank closed my account. Before closing my account, I was told to withdraw money from my account. My plan was to leave $5 and move on.

It turns out I made a mistake and my balance is $-2. I got a letter from USBank saying that if I do not pay I will be charged $25 a week.

I want to pay.

$2 is not a big deal. I can pay with paypal or bitcoin.

However, I am all the way in Indonesia.

I even have a check of $14 paid by amazon. I can send screenshot to USBank and they can cash it on my behalf.

A month ago they told me via email that I can pay once I go to US. I will never go back to US in years but they seem to say that it's not a problem.

Then, today, I got a letter from them saying that they will charge me $25 a week until I paid off my balance.

It's only $2.38

I emailed them again but haven't receive any reply.

What would be a solution for this? US bank seems to only accept wire. I asked them before and they said not to worry about it. If I login to their interface it says that I no longer have accounts.

Is the status of my account "closed".

I already contacted them but I worry that this $2 issue I may one day owe them huge amount of money.

Note:

I emailed them and I got this

> Thanks for emailing us with your concern. I'm sorry to inform you the
>   account has been charged off and sent to our Recoveries department
>   back in October 2016. Please contact us at 1-503-401-9991 between the
>   hours of 9:00 AM-6:30 PM ET, Monday-Friday and 8:00 AM-5:00 PM ET on
>   the last day of the month. Ask the representative to be transferred to
>   the recoveries department. If you have any further questions or
>   concerns, please don't hesitate to contact us back.

Looks like the $2 has become a big problem already.

Comment: Do you have a letter, email from Bank saying the account is closed?

Comment: Perhaps Western Union or a similar outfit can give you a USD check or money order, and you can mail that to US Bank.

Comment: Did they mail the collection letter to you in Indonesia? Does the letter have a valid USBank phone number on it?

Comment: Jim - do you mind mentioning the bank name/state?

Comment: Yes. The name is US Bank.

Comment: US Bank. I got an email that they have forwarded this to collection agency and I got to phone them. All over $2 negative balance.

Comment: USBank told me that they are cancelling the charge

Answer (score 7):

Do you know anyone in the US, still?  If so, ask them to close it for you.  $2.38 is well within the "if anybody I knew asked me to I would" range, and probably is for anyone you know well.  Offer to send them money via a wire transfer (or Western Union or whatever), but odds are if it's a friend or coworker they won't care about $2.

Comment: Not many. I can pay with paypal. I guess I talk to several employee at the bank.

Answer (score 4):

Call them ask for a delay on your $25 per week fee and send them a check and a written letter saying to close the account once the balance to zero.

If they deny your delay of $25 per week fee, send them a express package by Fedex, DHL or the post office.  That should run about $25, so in comparison to the fee its like paying one week.

Be sure to close your account and be clear on how to do so from overseas.

Comment: In Indonesia I don't even have a check. I can pay with paypal and bitcoin. I am still asking them how should I pay. I am concerned that the lending will cost a lot and that it will damage my credit record. I am not borrowing anything in US but you know I may come back as businessman or I may do biz with some people.

Comment: You can't get a cashiers check at a bank?